# swipe to change uiviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode5, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a `viewController` which contains data which will remain static on the top half of the `viewController`. The bottom half contains 4 buttons and 4 `UIViewControllers` linked to the 4 buttons which are loaded earlier. And on respective button click the respective `UIViewController` will be show and rest of them will be hidden. I am just making `viewController` visible and invisible on the button click.

I want to make them change on swipe. so the `UIViewController` will change with the swipe and the button state for the respective `UIViewController` will also change with swipe.

I am not using storyboard and using xcode5.

Comment: If u r changing view controller on swipe then why u need buttons?

Comment: @KananVora It has to be handled both way that viewcontroller should be changed on button click and also with swipe

Comment: why downvote please provide reasons for downvote?

Comment: Because you haven't proved you've researched the question significantly. What have you done/tried? What doesn't work? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 2):

One simple way - you can use `UITabBarController` to handle all this array of view controllers:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html
And to change them with swipe - just add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html like this:

`UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeTabs:)];
     [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
    [swipeRecognizer release]`;
And in `changeTabs:` do this

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:nextViewController];
```

Another more solid way is to use `UIPageViewController` : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

You wrote: `"so the uiviewcontroller will change with the swipe and the button state for the respective uiviewcontroller will also change with swipe."` - this is silly. Just use either tabs as I suggested and remove those buttons or use `UIPageViewController` which already has page indicators and will handle their logic itself

Comment: I have almost completed the application and its near deadline and client wants it to be handled both ways by clicking on button and also through swipe and I am new to IOS so donno what to do. please help me.